# Removing mc:Ignorable namesapces dynamically

Tags: xml, xslt-2.0, openxml

I am looking to remove any mc:ignorable namespace from an ooxml spec document.

For example (taken from a docx numbering.xml...)

```
<w:numbering xmlns:wpc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingCanvas" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships" xmlns:m="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/math" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:wp14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingDrawing" xmlns:wp="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/wordprocessingDrawing" xmlns:w10="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main" xmlns:w14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordml" xmlns:w15="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2012/wordml" xmlns:wpg="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingGroup" xmlns:wpi="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingInk" xmlns:wne="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2006/wordml" xmlns:wps="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingShape" mc:Ignorable="w14 w15 wp14"><w:numbering xmlns:wpc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingCanvas" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships" xmlns:m="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/math" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:wp14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingDrawing" xmlns:wp="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/wordprocessingDrawing" xmlns:w10="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main" xmlns:w14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordml" xmlns:w15="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2012/wordml" xmlns:wpg="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingGroup" xmlns:wpi="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingInk" xmlns:wne="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2006/wordml" xmlns:wps="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingShape" mc:Ignorable="w14 w15 wp14">
```

Notice the mc:ignorable at the end corresponding to w14 and w15 namespaces.

What is the correct way to remove any node using the ignorable namespaces. This needs to be done dynamically as it can change with any xml doc sent through pre-processing for validation.

**EDIT**

Including my current setup without any dynamic removal(only hardcoded namespaces)...

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output indent="no" method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="no" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

<!-- Identity transform. Also known as "Copy everything". -->
<xsl:template match="@* | node()" name="identity">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

And my hardcoded namespaces to be removed

```
    <xsl:template match="node()[namespace-uri()='http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingDrawing']|@*[namespace-uri()='http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingDrawing']" />
<xsl:template match="node()[namespace-uri()='http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordml']|@*[namespace-uri()='http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordml']" />
<xsl:template match="node()[namespace-uri()='http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/spreadsheetml/2009/9/ac']|@*[namespace-uri()='http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/spreadsheetml/2009/9/ac']" />
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
<xsl:variable xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" name="namespaces-to-remove" select="for $prefix in /*/tokenize(@mc:Ignorable, ' ') return namespace-uri-for-prefix($prefix, /*)"/>

<xsl:template  match="node()[namespace-uri() = $namespaces-to-remove] | @*[namespace-uri() = $namespaces-to-remove]"/>
```

Comment: I received a compiler error for missing the select attribute...which I do see you included so i'm confused what the syntax error is 

Compiler warnings:
  WARNING:  'org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl: Property 'http://javax.xml.XMLConstants/property/accessExternalDTD' is not recognized.'
ERROR:  'Syntax error in 'for $prefix in /*/tokenize(@mc:Ignorable, ' ') return namespace-uri-for-prefix($prefix, /*)'.'
FATAL ERROR:  'file:///C:/Users/abc/a/b/c/UTF-8: line 96: Required attribute 'select' is missing.'

Comment: You have tagged your question as xslt-2.0 so I have used that version of the language, to run it you need to use an XSLT 2.0 processor like Saxon 9. A quick online test like http://xsltransform.net/94rmq5H suggests the approach works.